# Can we have only 255 users connected to a LAN

Tags: c#, tcp, ip, lan

While developing a C# application I came across this problem, so as to get which user is connected I m using `ping()` function and sending **ping** to 255 users in a loop depending upon my own IP address and waiting for the reply!

but my question is We have more that 500 students in our hostels and every one is connected to LAN then how is IP address allocated to each device and how can I retrieve list of all users connected to LAN at a point of time.

I believe I was able to make my question clear!

Comment: Is the question "can we have only 255 users connected to a LAN, not more", "how is IP address allocated to each device", or "how to retrieve a list of users connected to LAN"? Those are very different questions.

Comment: @Mat: see my method to retrieve list of online users on lan is
1.Get my own IP like a.b.c.d
2.now run a loop from i = 1-255 and ping(a.b.c.i)
3. then wait for the ping to return

is there another method to get list of all users on LAN

Comment: @Joni: I would like to know about both

Comment: IP address allocation can run be made statically (each device has a fixed address) or dynamically (devices request an address for example from a DHCP server). Which one do you use? As to how to retrieve a list of connected nodes, can you assume that the devices will run software that answers to broadcast traffic, or can you not assume anything?

Comment: any option I can get list of all connected devices without having any extra software installed in other connected systems

Comment: If the IP addresses are assigned dynamically you may be able to get a list of IP addresses that are in use from the DHCP server. Or you might be able to get a list of connected nodes from the switch configuration. Otherwise you are pretty much forced to scan the network, for example by sending an ARP broadcast for every IP on the network. The devices, can they really be anything at all (laptops, smartphones, TVs, ...) or are they computers running Microsoft Windows?

Comment: There is no such thing as a LAN in TCP/IP. There are only subnets, defined by their subnet mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like more of a networking structure issue. When you have 500 people they would have to be segregated into network segments so instead of all the users having the same 192.168.0.XXX. Some devices might have 192.168.0.xxx and others might have 192.168.1.xxx. You would be able to verify this with your network admin.

Boils down to you will probably have to scan more than just one network range.

Good Luck!

Comment: @user2137302 the third part of the IP in 192.168.0.XXX or 192.168.1.xxx is that set as a static value by network admin or it is dynamically allocated?

Comment: Maybe there is confusion on the question. They would be limited to 255 devices per a.b.c.d (give d would be 1-255).

Comment: @mebjas that would be set by your network gear and would not be set via dhcp (automatically) Typically the 3rd number would be set by the immed upstream router.

Comment: @user2137302 thanks but there is one more question in my mind: is the default gateway the address among 192.168.0.XXX,192.168.1.xxx
or the address of the central device connected to internet

Comment: This will depend on how your network is setup. Our network here (also at a college) has static routes setup between routers so that 192.168.0.x can talk to a printer (for example) at 192.168.1.5. If these are not set up then you might not be able to talk between segments. This might be a security precaution or just isolation.

Comment: @mebjas Something else that you will have to keep in mind it that just using ping you will see all devices that are set to respond to pings. So they might be printers and the flip side is you can easily make a computer not reply to pings. So this might not be the most accurate way.

Comment: Can you tell me an alternative?

Comment: You can check out snmp or active directory. Those would help but the first you would need permissions or install a 'client' app on each of the computers you wanted to know status on or for the later, they would have to be on a domain. (highly unlikely (for the students) in a college environment.) After that you run out of options very quickly. I hope it helps. If so mark as answer.

Comment: No what if I want to retrieve the list without having my tool installed in other computers?

Comment: just like windows network folder shows list of all connected computers

Comment: I am not sure of any way to do that. The windows network folder uses a built in service in order to see other computers that are browse-able. Good luck on your project!